# Durundal Kendo Toolbar Custom command

Tags: jquery, asp.net, knockout.js, kendo-ui, durandal

In my Drundal View Model

I am trying to use custom toolbar command in Kendo Grid  as below

```
  ko.bindingHandlers.kendoGrid.options = {
            editable: "popup",
            toolbar:[{text:"Test",id:"custom",name:"custom"}]
        };
```

add event listener to button but this event is not firing at all

```
$(".k-grid-custom").click(function(e) {  
    console.log("[DEBUG MESSAGE] ", "query button clicked!");
});
```

Comment: Where do you have the `$(".k-grid-custom")` in your code? It has to come **after** the `ko.applyBindings` call... so you are probably trying to subscribe on the click before the grid has been rendered...

Comment: Hi this is in durudal view model

Comment: Ok, but you need to have the event subscription in the `bindingComplete` or in the `compositionComplete` callbacks...